# How to Find a Vector Field(/Differential Form) with Div(F) = 0 but F \ne Curl(A) on R^3\(S^1x{0})

Tags: differential-forms, vector-fields, de-rham-cohomology

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250702/finding-the-de-rham-cohomology-of-an-open-subset-of-bbbrn-minus-a-poin), it is outlined how to find a differential $n$-form on $U_0 = \mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{\text{pt}\}$ whose exterior derivative is zero but which is not the exterior derivative of an $(n-1)$-form.

Suppose I have $U_1 = \mathbb{R}^3\backslash(S^1 \times \{0\})$, so that there is a torus (which has empty boundary, and so is closed [as a manifold]) which does not bound in $U_1$; how do I find a vector field $\vec{F}$ (resp. a 2-form $\omega$) on $U_1$ with $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{F} = 0$ (resp. $d\omega = 0$) but which does not admit a vector potential function $\vec{A}$ on $U_1$ with $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A} = \vec{F}$ (resp. a 1-form $\theta$ on $U_1$ with $d\theta = \omega$)? This should exist by de Rham's Theorem and should have its integral over the torus, $\unicode{x222F}_{T^2} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S}$ (resp. $\unicode{x222F}_{T^2} \omega$), non-zero.

In principle, how do I extend this to $U_2 = \mathbb{R}^3\backslash(\text{Wedge of Two Circles})$ (which has a 2-holed-torus that has empty boundary but does not bound in $U_2$), $U_3 = \mathbb{R}^3\backslash(\text{Wedge of Three Circles})$ (which has a 3-holed-torus that has empty boundary but does not bound in $U_3$), etc.?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: (I don't even think this is in $\textit{Analysis on Manifolds}$ by Munkres https://smile.amazon.com/Analysis-Manifolds-James-R-Munkres-dp-0201510359/dp/0201510359/ or $\textit{Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology}$ by Bott and Tu https://smile.amazon.com/Differential-Algebraic-Topology-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387906134/; I'm not sure if it's in $\textit{From Calculus to Cohomology}$ by Madsen https://smile.amazon.com/Calculus-Cohomology-Rham-Characteristic-Classes/dp/0521589568/)

Comment: Can you write down a smooth retraction of $\Bbb R^3-S^1\times\{0\}$ to the torus? If so, pull back the area $2$-form on the torus.

Comment: @TedShifrin That sounds like a plan. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsUFBm1uENs

Comment: No, I'm not sure I can write down a retraction: where would the origin go? There's no retraction of the open unit ball in R^2 onto S^1. Thanks so much for replying, but I'll have to think about it.

Comment: You're actually correct. Try retracting onto a "torus with no hole", instead.

Comment: A torus centered on the depleted circle with x-y radius 1 and x-z/y-z radius 1/2? That sounds right; it's in keeping with this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961354/fundamental-group-of-bbb-r3-setminus-s1-with-explicit-deformation-retract. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmmm, no, I want to rotate a circle of radius $1$ about a circle of radius $1$ (centered at the origin). Then the "pinched torus" has all circles passing through the origin.

Comment: Right, I meant a  torus centered on the depleted circle with x-y radius 1 and x-z/y-z radius 1; I don't know why I said what I said.

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually, looking here https://www.math3ma.com/blog/clever-homotopy-equivalences, it appears $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash S^1$ is NOT homotopy equivalent to $T^2$; $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash [S^1 \cup \text{(z-axis)}]$ IS homotopy equivalent to $T^2$

Comment: Yes, I know. That’s why we need the torus with no hole, as I suggested a while ago.  Now the $z$-axis maps to the central point of the torus with no hole.

Comment: Thanks, I was unclear; thanks for replying